# How to deny read access to an ExecCGI directory

Tags: apache-2.2

First, I can't believe that that isn't the default behavior.  Second, yikes!  I don't know how long my code's been hanging out there, with all sort of cool secret stuff, just waiting for some hacker who knows Apache better than I do.

Comment: You have non-executable source code files in your ExecCGI directory why?

Comment: More info needed. What OS are you running on? How was apache installed/configured (straight from a repo with apt/yum/similar, or downloaded and installed by other means). Is the content visible via the web server or just to local users (are people able to see it with a `http://` URL in a browser or with an `ls` command?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `-Indexes` to disallow showing your CGI directory index:

`Options +ExecCGI -Indexes`

Comment: +1 We use `Options None +ExecCGI`, but yours works too for denying directory listing.

Answer (score 1):

To make this useful for future viewers (since [@Community](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community) bumped it anyhow), I'll answer with the relevant bits of what OP (who hasn't been here since January 20th) edited into the question.

---

> Here's what happened:
>
> We had some Python scripts available to the web, at /aux/file.py,
>   which were not surprisingly at /var/www/http/aux . Separately, we were
>   running an app server and Apache proxies through at /servlets/. A
>   contractor had constructed the WAR file by bundling up all the
>   generated files including the Python files (which are in a directory
>   also called aux, not surprisingly), so if you typed in
>   /servlets/aux/file.py, the web-server would ask the app-server for it
>   and the app-server would just supply the file. It was the latter URL
>   that this morning I happened to type in by accident and lo, the source
>   appeared.
>
> Until I realized the shear unlikelihood of what I had done, the
>   situation was rating about 8.3 on the sphincter scale. After a tense
>   half-hour or so I realized that it had nothing to do with the CGI (and
>   that serving files that were also executable would be not only foolish
>   but also impossible), and was able to address the real problems.

---